# MySQL unix_timestamp calculation

Tags: mysql

I have an `employees` table with a field called `start` which is a unix_timestamp of the date the employee started. I'm calculating their most recent anniversary using a loop in PHP

```
$year_start = $employee['start'];
while(strtotime('+1 year', $year_start) <= time()){
    $year_start = strtotime('+1 year', $year_start);
}
```

That works fine, but I'd like to do it as a "virtual field" in the SQL query. Anyone got a clever MySQL query that'll get the most recent anniversary in unix_timestamp?

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to do it in MySQL?

Comment: I'm using CakePHP for the project, it's easier to use virtualFields than adding the loop to the afterFind method loop. It's not a big deal if there isn't a way.
I fancy myself pretty good with SQL and haven't come up with a query... it'll bug me if I don't at least ask.

Comment: `unix_timestamp(date_add(from_unixtime(start), interval +1 year))`

Comment: @Barranka, thanks for the reply... that just gets the start date plus one year. It doesn't work if they've worked for over 2 years. BUT!!! That does give me an idea. I'll check back after some testing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Barranka alerting me to the existence of `date_add` I think I've got a solution.

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE_ADD ( FROM_UNIXTIME(start), interval +FLOOR( DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(start) )/365 ) year))
```